# pytest -- how do I use global / session-wide fixtures?

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest

I want to have a "global fixture" (in pytest they could also be called "session scoped fixtures") which does some expensive environment setup, like typically preparing a resource, which is then reused across test modules. The setup is something like this,

#### shared_env.py

would have a fixture doing something expensive, like starting up a Docker container, MySQL server, etc.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session")
def test_server():
    start_docker_container(port=TEST_PORT)
    yield TEST_PORT
    stop_docker_container()
```

#### test_a.py

would use the server,

```
def test_foo(test_server): ...
```

#### test_b.py

would use the same server

```
def test_foo(test_server): ...
```

It seems that pytest has support for this via `scope="session"`, but I can't figure out how to make the actual imports work. The current setup will given an error message like,

```
fixture 'test_server' not found
available fixtures: pytestconfig, ...
use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath] ' for help on them
```

Answer (score 30):

There is a convention in pytest which uses the special file named `conftest.py` and contains session fixtures.

I have extracted two very simple examples to give a quick start. They do not use classes.

Everything taken from http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-session-scoped-fixtures/

**Example 1:**

The fixture is not executed unless supplied as an argument to a `test_*` function. The fixture `some_resource` is executed prior to calling the referencing function, in this case `test_2`. The finalizer on the other hand is executed at the end.

*conftest.py:*

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")

def some_resource(request):
  print('\nSome resource')
 
  def some_resource_fin():
    print('\nSome resource fin')

  request.addfinalizer(some_resource_fin)
```

*test_a.py:*

```
def test_1():
  print('\n Test 1')
 
def test_2(some_resource):
  print('\n Test 2')

def test_3():
  print('\n Test 3')
```

*Result:*

```
$ pytest -s
======================================================= test session starts ========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0
rootdir: /tmp/d2, inifile: 
collected 3 items 

test_a.py 
 Test 1
.
Some recource

 Test 2
.
 Test 3
.
Some resource fin
```

**Example 2:**

Here the fixture is configured with `autouse=True`, so it is executed once at the beginning of the session, and it does not have to be referenced. Its finalizer is executed at the end of the session.

*conftest.py:*

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)

def auto_resource(request):
  print('\nSome resource')
 
  def auto_resource_fin():
    print('\nSome resource fin')

  request.addfinalizer(auto_resource_fin)
```

*test_a.py:*

```
def test_1():
  print('\n Test 1')
 
def test_2():
  print('\n Test 2')

def test_3():
  print('\n Test 3')
```

*Result:*

```
$ pytest -s
======================================================= test session starts ========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0
rootdir: /tmp/d2, inifile: 
collected 3 items 

test_a.py 
Some recource

 Test 1
.
 Test 2
.
 Test 3
.
Some resource fin
```