# How to load environment variables from file using python-dotenv before loading pytest scritps?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pytest, integration-testing

I have tests which on inside docker container with https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose, but it does take too long for the container to start up/shutdown. Then, I would like to let docker-compose run tests only CI machine or when need.

For this, I used this way of defining tests on `simple_test_runner.py`:

```python
import os

THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY = os.environ.get('RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY')

if RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY:
    def test_simple(run_process, load_env):
        output, returncode = run_process("python3 " + THIS_FOLDER + "/simple_test.py")
        assert returncode == 0

else:
    def test_simple(function_scoped_container_getter):
        container = function_scoped_container_getter.get("container_name")
        exec = container.create_exec("python3 /simple_test.py")
        ...
```

This works file if I export `RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY=1` before calling `pytest -vs .`, but if I try to use https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv in my `conftest.py`:

```python
from dotenv import load_dotenv

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def load_env():
    print("Loading .env file")
    load_dotenv()
```

The environment variables are only loaded after python test loaded the `simple_test_runner.py`. Then, my tests are always running inside docker instead of outside it when `RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY=1` is defined.

How can I make `pytest` to call `load_dotenv()` before my switch `if RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY:` is evaluated inside my tests?

Or do you know an alternative to `if RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY:` which allows me to use `load_dotenv()` and switch between running my tests inside docker-compose or not?

Related:

1. https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv
2. [How to load variables from .env file for pytests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763151/how-to-load-variables-from-env-file-for-pytests)
3. [pytest -- how do I use global / session-wide fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899001/pytest-how-do-i-use-global-session-wide-fixtures)

Answer (score 0):

The code I originally posted is working:

```python
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def load_env(request):
    file = THIS_FOLDER + '/.env'
    if request.config.getoption("verbose") > 0:
        print("Loading", file, file=sys.stderr)
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path=file)
```

The problem was that when I had tested, I had set my environment variable to `RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY=` (the empty string). This was causing `dotenv` to not override my environment variable. Once I unset the variable with `bash unset RUN_TESTS_LOCALLY`, `dotenv` was finally loading the environment file correctly.